What is the correlation between Brownian noise's low frequency components and the actual movement of particles?
I do have some crude training in mathematics, but I'm not a physicist or engineer. So I'd appreciate a simple not too technical explanation.
I conceptually understand how hitting a piece of wood will produce lower frequencies than a bar of aluminium for, let's say, a normalised volume of material.
And there is a direct correlation between the actual movement of the sound-radiating surface of the sample and a waveform capture of the sound produced.
Now, in the case of Brownian noise and Brownian motion, what movements of particles in the sample are the ones producing the lower frequencies of a Brownian noise vs the ones producing the higher frequencies?

Addressing the question on Brownian motion:
If you check wikipedia's color of noise page, the little blurb on Brownian noise say:
Brownian noise can be generated with temporal integration of white noise.
which pretty much answers the question. But I'll break it down.
A totally uncorrelated sequence of random numbers has a white noise spectrum. Gonna try to break this down no mathematically as possible....hmmm...lemme think.
Ok, say you pick a random number, $x_0$, at $t=0$, and then you let the generator run for a while, and the take a new random number $x_i$ at $t=\tau$.
The numbers are totally unrelated, and time (or number of samples) between them just doesn't matter. This is what uncorrelated means.
There is a special case, though, when $\tau=0$:
$$ x_i = x_0 $$
so they are maximally correlated ($1$ for discrete samples, and $\infty$ in the continuous limit--but that's a detail).
Basically the autocorrelation function is:
$$ R = \delta(t) $$
which $\infty$ at $t=0$ and $0$ everywhere else.
In the discrete case, the autocorrelation looks like:
$$(\cdots, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,\cdots) $$
The autocorrelation and frequency (power) spectrum are intimately related though a theorem (I always forget the name).
Basically, since the correlation does not depend on $\tau$, the power spectrum at frequency $f=1/\tau$ is constant: that is white noise.
The "next" movement in Brownian motion is totally random and unrelated to prior movements; however, we're talking about the total distance moved since $t=0$, so we have to add all the movements up (a cumulative sum, so-to-speak).
A key part of Brownian motion is that the deviation from the start grows with the number of steps, $N$, as $\sqrt N$ (randomly, ofc--that's the expectation value).
Now let restate the wiki-quote:
Brownian noise can be generated with temporal integration of white noise.
The longer the temporal integration, the more steps are included--infact, if we pick two times:
$$ \tau_2 = 2\tau_1 $$
the total number of steps is:
$$ N_2 = 2N_1 $$
and the deviation grows as
$$ \sqrt N_2 = \sqrt{2N_1} = \sqrt 2 \sqrt N $$
A quick aside: If we consider this two consecutive periods, that is: we wait $\tau_1$, the particle moves $d$ with standard deviation $\sigma_d = \sqrt{N_1}$.
Now if we restart and do it again, waiting another $\tau_1$, another $N_1$ steps, we move $d'$ with standard deviation
$$ \sigma_{d'} = \sqrt{N1} $$
To get the standard deviation of two random processes, we add them in quadrature (which is the single most important thing to know) so:
$$ \sigma_{d + d'} = \sqrt{\sigma_d^2 + \sigma^2_{d'}}$$
$$ \sigma_{d + d'} = \sqrt{\sqrt{N_1}^2 + \sqrt{N_1}^2}$$
$$ \sigma_{d + d'} = \sqrt{N_1 + N_1}$$
$$ \sigma_{d + d'} = \sqrt{2 N_1}$$
$$ \sigma_{d + d'} = \sqrt 2 \sqrt{N_1}$$
$$ \sigma_{d + d'} = \sqrt{N_2}$$
which is the same as just waiting $\tau_2$..so it has to grow as $\sqrt N$ to be self-consistent.
So back to the quote:
Brownian noise can be generated with temporal integration of white noise.
The expected amount of motion (standard deviation) grows as
$$\sigma(\tau) = \sqrt \tau $$
or, the variance is:
$$ \sigma^2(\tau) = \langle d^2 \rangle \propto \tau $$
This distance deviation is "the signal". The power in a signal goes as its variance,$\sigma^2$:
$$ \sigma^2(\tau) \propto \tau  $$
That is, the variance grown linearly.
In terms of frequency ($f = 1\tau$):
$$ \sigma^2(f) \propto \frac 1 f $$
Now here you can't avoid math, the density of that is the derivative over logarithmic abscissa (there's also mixed terminology across fields as how the PSD is quoted--I do it for a living and can't remember the various standards.... meters per root Hz, or square meters per Hz...you can delve into that here: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/45574/power-spectral-density-of-brownian-motion-despite-non-stationary):
$$ P(f) \propto  1/f^2 $$
e.g.:

